# Android gradle google-services build failed "Duplicate Entry"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

**Edit:**

I changed this line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

I changed the classpath to be:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha7'
```

And updated the gradle version to 2.10 to fix the other issue I mentioned. Now I am having this error whenever I build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Original Question**

Out of nothing, my app wouldn't successfully build. I tried updating google-services and still I am getting an error.

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info.class

I am also getting an error in my gradle, at the line:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```

saying that some google libraries are of version 8.4.0 and some in 8.1.0. I tried upgrading the google library to 8.4.0. The gradle won't build and gives me the following error:

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If 
 using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in 
/Users/essam/Desktop/Apptuto/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties 
to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Here is my gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

The app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "findbugs"
apply plugin: "pmd"
android {
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my package name is written here"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}


}
findbugs {
ignoreFailures = true
toolVersion = "2.0.1"
reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs")
effort = "max"
}

pmd {
ignoreFailures = true
reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/pmd")
ruleSets = [
        "basic",
        "braces"
]
}


dependencies {
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.7@aar') {
    transitive = true

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/intercom/intercom-maven'
    }
}

compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.+@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

}

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`

Answer (score 1):

it's a rule that all google play services should be using the same version
while I can see only one line using 8.1.0, you might have another library using 8.4.0 , just edit yours to 8.4.0 instead of 8.1.0

now for the other error, I don't know, it didn't happen to me I copied your exact gradle and it compiled

if it kept appearing, try removing your second line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

why are you using this any way?

Comment: I made some changes that I will edit my post mentioning them. I tried removing the second line, but it gave me a lot of errors; as it didn't find the library. Regarding your question: Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Could you post the changes? Thanks!

Comment: "why are you using this any way?" Because it is written here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project